# What component did I miss to export? Error type is invalid...error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am sure I exported all my components, yet I keep getting the same error:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `CustomNavbar`.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home.js';
import Navbar from './CustomNavbar.js';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

CustomNavbar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class CustomNavbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    <Link to="/">My Page</Link>
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle />
            </Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Nav pullRight>
                <NavItem eventKey={1} componentClass={Link} to="/">
                    Home
                </NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}
```

Home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Jumbotron, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
            <Jumbotron>
                <h1>Hello, this is my page</h1>
            </Jumbotron>
            <Link to="/about">
            <Button bsStyle="primary">About</Button>
            </Link>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
import Navbar from './CustomNavbar.js';
```

to

```
import CustomNavbar from './CustomNavbar.js';
```

And

Change

```
  <Navbar />
```

To

```
  <CustomNavbar />
```

In App.js

Comment: This shouldn't make any difference. You can name the default export anything you like. the error message also says that it's something inside the CustomNavbar render method, not App's render method. it's probably a typo using a react-bootstrap component